# How do I remove libavcodec53 and libavutil51 before installing ubuntu restricted extras?

Tags: uninstall

Hello I want to install ubuntu-restricted-extras after I installed Ubuntu 12.10  I get an error to remove libavcodec53 and libavutil51. Can someone please tell me how I remove the above items from my computer.  Thank you.
Gil

Comment: Worked for me. Needed to load VLC and the softwar ctr. said I had to get rid of those two files. When I ran that script it showed all the junk it would replace it with and I said yes. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`sudo apt-get remove libavcodec-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51`

Comment: its sudo apt-get remove libavcodec-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51 , please check and update your answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as a pure Linux Noob, I think that you are both wrong. I think in this application it should be: `sudo apt-get remove libavcodec53 libavutil51`

The OP wants to install the Restricted Extras package, not uninstall it.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE So, unless I am missing something, your change to my answer was just to add a blank space at the beginning and end of the code? What is the point of this?